# Unable to get ruleChainConnections for root rule chain for thingsboard 3.4.4

Tags: thingsboard

I tried to get ruleChainConnections data for root rule chain even gave connection with another rule chain i am getting ruleChainConnections: null

I tried below API
this is the end point i used /api/ruleChain/{ruleChainId}/metadata
as per some suggestions i restarted server as well but no luck